# add_action() but function is never called

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom wordpress plugin in which I'm defining a custom post type and at one point I'm calling add_action to set custom column in the admin.
The 'manage_[custompostname]_posts_columns' is working great, but the 'manage_[custompostname]_posts_custom_column' do not.

```
add_filter('manage_bbc_cp_game_posts_columns', bbc_cp_game_table_head');
function bbc_cp_game_table_head( $defaults ) {
    $columns = array(
        'team_id' => 'Equipe',
        'opponent_id' => 'Adversaire',
        'gamedatetime' => 'Date / heure',
        'score' => 'Score'
    );
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_bbc_cp_game_posts_custom_column', 'bbc_cp_game_table_content', 10, 2 );
function bbc_cp_game_table_content( $column, $post_id ) { die('it should work'); }
```

The second `add_action` returns `true`, but the function is never called.
I'd really appreciate if any of you had an idea of what could be the issue, or how to debug it.

Thanks,

Comment: Note that if the custom post type has 'hierarchical' => true, then the correct action hook to use is manage_pages_custom_column. [Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)

Comment: That was the issue ! ... of all the custom post types I've created, if found two of them that had 'hierarchical' => true for no reason. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.
Can't figure out how come it worked for a while before the problem showed up.